# RedirectToAction is not working in dot net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am having a partial view in another view. The partial view have a form submitting data to controller. The name of partial view is `CreateContentType`.

After submitting data I am trying to redirect to `ContentTypes` action like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateContentType(ContentTypeViewModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TikWebZi.Model.Users.User>(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault().Value);
            model.WebsiteOperatorId = user.UserId;
            var inputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            dynamic serviceResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(TikWebZi.UI.Components.HttpHelper.MakeRequest(Startup.StaticConfiguration.GetSection("Settings").GetSection("ServiceUrl").Value + "content/createcontenttype", inputJson, false));
            if (serviceResponse.ResponseCode == 100)
            {
                TempData["Success"] = serviceResponse.ResponseMessage;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Error"] = serviceResponse.ResponseMessage;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Error"] = "Please fill all fields";
        }
        return RedirectToAction("contenttypes", "content", new { id = model.WebsiteId });
}
```

And here is the `ContentTypes` action result:

```
public ActionResult ContentTypes(int id)
{
        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TikWebZi.Model.Users.User>(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault().Value);
        dynamic serviceResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(TikWebZi.UI.Components.HttpHelper.MakeNoneJsonRequest(Startup.StaticConfiguration.GetSection("Settings").GetSection("ServiceUrl").Value + "website/getwebsite", "websiteId;userId", id + ";" + user.UserId.ToString(), true));
        if (serviceResponse.ResponseCode == 100)
        {
            ViewBag.Website = serviceResponse.ResponseData;
        }
        return View();
}
```

Here is the `ContentTypes` view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Item</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            @Html.Partial("CreateContentType")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the below is the `CreateContentType` partial view:

```
@model TikWebZi.UI.Areas.Dashboard.Models.ContentTypeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("createcontenttype", "content", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createcontenttype" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="WebsiteId" value="@ViewBag.Website.WebsiteId" />
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:130px;"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
    </div>
}
```

The above action result and `ContentTypes` action result both are in the `Content` Controller.

But the redirection is not working and the page redirect to `CreateContentType` after submitting.

What is wrong here?!

Comment: Hi @Hamid Reza, I have tested your code and could redirect successfully. Please debug the code and check if  `model.WebsiteId` have int value.

Comment: @Rena Its an int value.

Answer (score 1):

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(ContentTypes), new { id = model.WebsiteId }, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

if both actions are in the same controller, I usually just call an action as a function

```
public ActionResult CreateContentType(ContentTypeViewModel model)
{
       .....
        return  ContentTypes( model.WebsiteId);
}
```

If it still doesn't redirect it  means that it cathes exeption before reaching redirecting.

Comment: @HamidReza It is  just impossible!!! Compiller will always call a function.   Can you post  the whole code of CreateContentType and  ContentTypes actions, pls?

Comment: You still didn't put any code. It  gets exception somewhere,  before rediredting. I would like to check your code.

Comment: I added some details to my CreateContentType action result but there is not any exceptions there. The item is created and the debugger hits the last line without any exception.

Comment: And  you are going to tell me that computer refuses to call "return ContentTypes" ?  why you don't post ContentTypes action code too?

Comment: I added it too.

Answer (score 0):

Are sure this line in CreateContentType partial view is correct? Why do you assign "createcontenttype" to id?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("createcontenttype", "content", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createcontenttype" }))
```

Don't you need something like this?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("createcontenttype", "content", FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model.WebsiteId }))
```